# Checking for solution on application crash

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

How can i disable the "checking for solution" when a error occurs in my program?

*What i want is that it directly goes to the error inside Visual Studio 2010. Now i have to wait like 1 minute before i can select debug and see my error.*

Did not have this behavior before and not really sure what changed in the environmental settings.

I was debugging with 2 breakpoints when this behavior occurs every time a error happens outside the breakpoints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a settings of the OS rather than of Visual Studio, to disable checking for solution feature on Windows 7 :

Click on start, type: Choose how to report problems, then change it to Never check for solutions .

Answer (score 1):

If Visual Studio stops reponding  it shows "Checking for solution".

At this stage VS is trying to fix the problem and promts to "send report" if user allows that.

It makes not so much sense to disable this, nor it is allowed in Visual Studio.

Comment: Would be a first that i actually ever see this solving anything though. When developing this is not really useful at all (nor is it ever). Just wondered if it could not go directly to my code.

Answer (score 0):

What if you put a tick on the check box:
Debug -> Exception -> Common Language Runtime Exceptions?

Does it stop immediately?

Comment: This is not answer. Please, next time add it as a comment.